# Not able to call a c# function through javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, asp.net

i have an anchor tag `<a></a>` and through Jquery i am handling the click event on it.onclick i get the x and y position i.e `xIndex` and `yIndex` respectively.
i want to store this two values in database and for that i have a method `StoreXY(string XIndex,string YIndex)`at backend in c# `test.aspx.cs` file . but as i have values of x and y position in javascript variables, i need to call the `StoreXY()` method through javascript. Following is the code i am using.

test.aspx

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
<a class="Build" href="#">Build</a>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".Build").click(function () {

       var r = parseInt($("#rows").val());
       var c = parseInt($("#cols").val());


       $(".outerDiv .isWalkable").each(function () {
       var x1 = $(this).index();
       var xIndex = (x1 % (c)) + 1;
       var yIndex = Math.floor(x1 / c) + 1;

        //calling c# function

        PageMethods.StoreXY(xIndex,yIndex);
        function onSucess(result) {
             alert(result);
        }
        function onError(result) {
              alert('Something wrong.');
        }
        //alert to just know that click event is actully handled
        alert(xIndex + '-' + yIndex);


        });
     });

 });

 </script>
```

test.aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string StoreXY(string Xindex, string Yindex)
    {
        SiteLogic SL = new SiteLogic();
        Site ste = SL.SelectByID(Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ID"]));
        Walkable W = new Walkable();
        W.X = Convert.ToInt32(Xindex);
        W.Y = Convert.ToInt32(Yindex);
        W.SiteID = ste.SiteID;
        WalkableLogic wlc = new WalkableLogic();
       int x= wlc.Insert(W);
       if (x > 0)
           return "Successfull";
       else return "Unsuccessfull";
    }
```

Now i am able to get the alert with x and y position values printed but the c# method in 'test.aspx.cs' file is not called and so no entry is inserted in database. How do i call 'StoreXY()' method from javascript?

Comment: Have you set a break point in the page method to see if it is called or see what is going on there? Are there any javascript errors in this console? You are also missing a comma between your success and error javascript functions, is this a typo in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the success and fail functions in your  call to the Page method:

```
function onSucess(result) {
     alert(result);
}
function onError(result) {
      alert('Something wrong.');
}    
PageMethods.StoreXY(xIndex,yIndex, onSuccess, onError);

//alert to just know that click event is actully handled
//May Fire before the above are complete.
alert(xIndex + '-' + yIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jQuery's [post method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to send the values, first using [param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) to serialize your x/y indices:

```
    var things = { Xindex: xIndex, Yindex: yIndex };
    var data = $.param(things);
    $.post(url_to_your_method, data, function (result) {
        // doing stuff...
    });
```

'result' will be the string that storeXY is returning. The $.post() method is shorthand for $.ajax() which will let you manipulate server side code.